# How to change environment name keeping numbering

Tags: environments, templates, tag

I have an environment defined by SVJour3 which is example:

```
\begin{example}
    \emph{lelien} → \emph{leli‐e-n}
\end{example}
```

From which I get:

*Example 1 lelien → leli-e-n*

I have introduced in the preamble:

```
\renewcommand{\example}{e}
```

I get now:

e *lelien → leli-e-n*

As you see I could change the name, but I have lost the numbering and other formatings like line brake and italic, I need to keep at least numbering, anybody knows how?

I have also tried with `\renewenvironment{example}` but no success

Comment: The word "Example"  in "Example 1" is not directly related to the name "example" of the environment. In order to keep the environment name as it currently is, while getting "Text 1" instead of "Example 1" in the output, you could try `\renewcommand{\examplename}{Text}`.

Comment: That was one of the things I tried and does nothing, I tried again just in case, but again nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that SVJour3 has a template which I did modify, then I have regenerated the tex file and things went the way I wanted.

[By **regenerate** I mean: Close the tex file, deleted the files .aux. log .out .gz, and open again the tex file after editing the templates mentioned below.]

I have located the SVJour3 package at:

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/LaTeX_DL_468198_240419/
```

where **LaTeX_DL_468198_240419/** is the package directory.

Inside this directory there is a file called `svjour3.cls` I have edited the lines:

```
\spn@wtheorem{example}{Example}{\itshape}{\rmfamily}
```

to

```
\spn@wtheorem{example}{E}{\itshape}{\rmfamily}
```

and (in the % English section --there are also a German and a French sections--)

```
\def\examplename{Example}%
```

to

```
\def\examplename{E}%
```